# What are some alternative ways to say "read the following for more"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, alternatives

Do all these mean the same:

Read the following for more.

Refer to the following for more information.

Further reading.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the following for more.
   This may mean read the following for more detailed explanation, or simply continue reading for more of the same: it may be a continuation of the story or discussion.
2. Refer to the following for more information.
   This means, if you want more details about what you have been reading, or more explanation that goes more in depth than the original text, read more here.
3. Further reading.
   This is the same as number two, just more professional.

The differences between these meanings are pretty subtle, and have a lot to do with tone. They also progress in formality, one being pretty casual, 3 being formal, and 2 somewhere in between.